# PHP - working with tables and JQuery

Tags: php, jquery

I have a task - Input:
1. An array of columns and types of the columns (2 dimensions array)
2. name of the table in SQL
3. table index

Output:
Building a dynamic table that show the data from this table. Each row should have 2 buttons - edit and delete. and also an empty row with a button - create.

If i want to edit or delete a row, i dont want to go to another page, i need to use JQuery and after edit - the row should become as something that i can change, and if i delete, it would be deleted.

I know how to build the table (with for loop)
But which JQuery to use and how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many solutions out there for dynamic table building.

First and foremost, many people will recommend [datatables](https://datatables.net/). It's a **massive** jQuery plugin that I personally found unnecessary complex and takes a while to get to grips with - however it's very powerful.

You'll need to be utilizing AJAX, which is the asynchronous (in-the-background) calls to the page where you retrieve your data server-side (most commonly via PHP). You can read about that [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). This is *very* simple and there are tutorials all over the net for that.

Finally, once you've learned AJAX, I (personally) perform the following:

- AJAX to get my data
- When the data is back in a variable, say 'data' returned by the `success()` function within the AJAX call, I dynamically build the table element to contain the data required (usually utilising jQuery's `$.each(data, function (key, values) { ...` method), and create a load of `<tr>` elements.
- I append these elements to the table.
- I write custom functions to detect the differences between the rows on-screen and those that aren't.

Personally, I'd write this yourself - you'll learn a lot more that way and may be in a better position to use datatables in the future to it's fullest potential.

---

**Code Example**

Let's say you've figured out the AJAX, because I'm *not* writing that for you - it's all over the net. In the success function, build your table elements.

```
success: function(data) {
    var rows = "";
    $.each(data, function(key, values) {
        rows += "<tr><td>" + values.name + "</td></tr>";
        // Add as much extra markup as you want here
    });

    // Finally, add this to the table
    $('#yourTable').prepend(rows);
}
```

*Note: This is completely off the top of my head, so worth checking first ;)*

A simple example, this question will be closed soon, but hopefully regardless this information will set you on the right track.

Comment: Just a note regarding your example: 1. You aren't adding any `<tr>` for each row. 2. Usually, you want to `append` rows, not `prepend` :)

Comment: @Johan Good spot! The reason I prepend is I want to see the latest additions *at the top*, rather than scrolling to the bottom each time.

Comment: Thought I might as well mention it since some people tend to mix them :) Anyway, +1 for a good example

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume that you create your rows with an html5 data attribute called `id` where each row id is stored.

A generated row would look something like this:

```
<tr>
    <!--some cells-->
    <td>
        <input type="button" class="rowdeletebutton" data-id="1">
    </td>
</tr>
```

Now, bind an event to the delete button and post the delete data to the server using a jQuery ajax call. Since the rows are dynamically generated, we need to make use of event delegation. The `on()` method with 3 arguments takes care of this for us:

```
$(document).on('click', '.rowdeletebutton', function(){

    var id = $(this).data('id');

    $.ajax({
        url: 'page.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { rowIdToDelete: id },
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data.Message);
        }
    });

});
```

And finally, handle the ajax call on the server (the page that I called `page.php`):

```
$idToDelete = $_POST['rowIdToDelete'];

if(isset($idToDelete))
{
    //delete the row with id = $idToDelete

    //and assuming everything went well, notify the client:

    $responseToClient = 
        array('Message' => 'Row ' . $idToDelete . ' successfully deleted' );

    echo json_encode($responseToClient);
}
```

Same principle goes for the edit button.